# Truncate Table with Delete Button

Tags: php, mysql, sql, truncate

I tried this but it didn't work, please i need support, i want a situation when i click on the delete button, i will truncate and empty the table.

```
This is the del.php file

<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "admin101";
    $dbname = "school";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    if (isset($_REQUEST['delete'])) {
        $myquery = mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE student");

        if ($myquery) {
            echo "Deleted successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $myquery . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }
?>
```

The HTML below.

```
<form method="post" action="del.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete">
</form>
```

Comment: First off you're mixing `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: ^-- this, and `mysql_*` function were deprecated in php 5 and removed in php 7

Comment: Still Got Error

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean when you say "it didn't work"

Comment: You're saying "Still got error" but you ignored @Daan's comment. If you updated your code locally you should update it on SO as well so we can help a little more.

Comment: i have updated the code with @Daan's suggestion, but still didnt work that was why i said still got errors.